# When a person (child) should cover something in soap

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In Russian we have a verb "**Намыль**", which means take soap (assuming either wet soap or dry soap depending on context) and rub it to have it cover something. What is the equivalent in English?

I thought the word "**soap**" as a verb would help me out but unfortunately it means "***wash with soap***" while I needn't include washing.

I can't find the right word or phrase to use in English.

**Edit**: We mostly use it when we distinguish two actions. When, for example, a person is in a bath tub and asks somebody to cover his body (back or head for instance) in soap he would say this verb.

Comment: Does the Russian verb assume that the soap is wet, and that you're covering something in soap suds? Or does it also include the case where the soap is dry, and you're just leaving a thin layer of residue on the object that you're rubbing it against?

Comment: It can either be wet or dry depending on context.

Comment: Do you mean to create a lather (with water)?  What kind of soap are we talking about?  Clothing detergent?  Hand soap?  Dishwashing liquid? Saddle soap? And what is the "something" that a "child" should cover? Why child?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Mostly we use to speak about covering body parts or furniture with soap. Dishwashing liquid can also be used but rarely. I'll add some more context.

Comment: It's a [cop-out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cop_out), but I would say "Could you **do** my back". I'd allow the context to carry the meaning.

Comment: @JamesK This could mean anything. There's plenty of actions to execute.

Comment: "Намыль" is the imperative (command form) of "намылить" which according to Ozhegov's dictionary means: "to rub soap onto someone or something, to wash using soap suds." So "Намыль!" could be translated "Soap it up.", "Get them soapy.", "Use soap.", "Use more soap.", "Suds them up.", etc.

Comment: @DavidC The first definition in Ozhegov's dictionary is the most accurate - **to rub soap onto someone or something**

Comment: Interestingly, Google Translate perfectly translates `Намыль` to `Lather`, the answer you accepted. I'm not suggesting you resort to GT for these cases, I just find it interesting.

Comment: @That1Guy In very rare cases do I turn to GT for help. I don't trust it.

Comment: That's good policy, lol

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are looking for the word "Lather", used as a verb.  Often in spoken AmE "up" is included after.

> Lather up my back.

If you are talking specifically about soaping someone's hair you would use, "Shampoo".

> Would you shampoo my hair, please.

Comment: The "up" is common in British English, too :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find reference to the verb **"to shampoo"** being used in the context of applying soap onto somebody's head. )))

Answer (score 12):

The way I see it, the verb **to soap** does cover your requirements. Namely, it doesn't require washing.
From http://www.dictionary.com/browse/soap?s=t: "to rub, cover, lather, or treat with soap."

If you want to specify that it wasn't washed with soap but just covered, you can first say **soap** and afterwards **rinse**, indicating that water was applied at a later time.

Comment: +1.  And if we're trying to convey the idea that the soap should be thoroughly applied, we'd say **soap up**.

Comment: **soap up** means to cover in soap thoroughly?

Comment: @SovereignSun: **up** conveys the idea that the action is performed to a degree not less than what is called for and possibly then some.  To **soap up** means to apply the soap with the requisite coverage and vigor, using a *goodly* amount of soap.  When the doctor **scrubs up** before performing surgery, he or she is giving the hands more than a quick perfunctory scrub.. When someone **beats you up**, they don't land only a punch or two, they give you a drubbing.

Answer (score 7):

> In russian we have a verb "Намыль", which means take soap (assuming either wet soap or dry soap depending on context) and rub it to have it cover something. What is the equivalent in English?

There isn't a neat single word that communicates this succinctly in English.

*Lather X/lather up X* means to create, spread, or cover something with foam.  It works with the context of soap, but sounds a little "instructive" in a bathing context.  A parent wouldn't really tell their child "Lather your face with soap" but it might be something you read on the back of a bottle of soap or similar.

*Soap* and *soap up* do basically mean *lather (up) X with soap* but as *soap* is not too commonly used of a verb it can catch a listener off guard unless they are expecting you to talk about soaping things up.  It can also mean to just apply soap to an object versus putting soap on something and then scrubbing it.

Phrases like *scrub X with soap* or *wash down X with soap* will work.

Comment: Correct.  A parent would say, "Wash your face."  If they wanted to tell the child to wash their face.  However, if they wanted the child's face "soaped up" they might add, "Be sure to lather it up."  Lather is the word that best answers OP.  Doubtful that they would add, "Be sure to wash down your face."  That, unfortunately, means nothing.

Comment: The whole child can be washed down. *You've been playing out in the mud. We need to wash you down.*

Comment: "Washing down" is something done in bulk to an object, like a dirty car or a cement floor. Using it to describe a muddy child sounds to me like spraying them down with a water hose, rather than normal washing.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham Are prisoners also washed down?

Answer (score 1):

A parent would say to their child "make sure to wash behind your ears" clean or scrub are interchangable with the word wash.

Comment: That doesn't help, too basic.